# Call vc++ dll in c#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

I have a dll in vc++ and the corresponding header file(.h file),Now I have to call this dll in c#.
And I do not have any idea about calling conventions.

In header file there is a function prototype like:

```
typedef void CBOnStop_VC( int nFGHandle, unsigned int nChannel, void* pClientData );
```

Now I want to call this function in c#.

Any Idea?

Comment: [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx) is the canonical way. And you ought to have some ideas about the calling conventions.

Comment: This answer help you : [C++ DLL call from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9719226/47733)

Answer (score 0):

you can use theses steps

```
1. compile your classe with the /clr switch

#include "NativeType.h"

public ref class ManagedType
{
     NativeType*   NativePtr; 

public:
     ManagedType() : NativePtr(new NativeType()) {}
     ~ManagedType() { delete NativePtr; }

     void ManagedMethod()
      { NativePtr->NativeMethod(); } 
}; 

2.Add a reference to your ManagedType assembly

ManagedType mt = new ManagedType();
mt.ManagedMethod();
```